# im have trouble with adding pos printer to posdm (configuration.xml or command line adddevice)

Tags: c#, wpf, pos, posprinter, pointofservice

I am having trouble with adding my Pos Printer to PosDM in Configurattion XML and with command line add device. 
i had searched a lot about this but got nothing Useful

i had tried the command line add device like:

"posdm adddevice SWD\PRINTENUM{9475957E-9973-435B-AF15-4591F5938233} /type:PosPrinter /soname:"EPSON TM-T82 ReceiptSA4"

by using this i got "no SO found that matches!"
i also added the logical name of device in configuration.xml:
but when i use the command "Posdm listdevices" i doesnt show me my printer

Comment: This is an old version of the article, but since these questions are still unresolved, please contact EPSON support for details on how to use it. [Print Arabic Characters using POS SDK and Epson T20II Receipt Printer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cab04a2d-8e38-4037-bb4d-2419798d13ea/print-arabic-characters-using-pos-sdk-and-epson-t20ii-receipt-printer?forum=Offtopic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"SWD\PRINTENUM{9475957E-9973-435B-AF15-4591F5938233}" is the DevicePath as a standard Windows desktop printer.

EPSON OPOS/OPOS for.NET should not support that mode.

If it is visible on the device manager, it is a usage mistake.

Disconnect the printer, uninstall the printer driver, use the OPOS ADK for.NET, see Appendix-C in the appropriate printer manual, change the hardware settings, and reinstall the device driver (USB serial?) .

Configurattion XML of PosDM settings should be set in the GUI by running the SetupPOS tool of EPSON OPOS for.NET as an administrator instead of the command line.

For details, refer to the SetupPOS User's Reference Manual.

Answer (score 0):

To set the default printer in code behind try:

```
app.ActivePrinter = "EPSON TM-T82 ReceiptSA4";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a way to use a standard Windows desktop printer, not POS for.NET.